# Word security warning not prompted, macro not run before checking VBE (Alt+F11)

Tags: vba, ms-word, macros

This MS Word document with macro in int (`.docm`), there are a couple of content controls and some macro behind them.

The issue is: when opened directly for the first time, no security warning is prompted (the 'Showing the Message Bar' option is turned on, and Macro settings is 'Disable all macros **with** notifications' in Trust Center), the macro will not fire as supposed to, but when I open VBE using `Alt`+`F11` without doing nothing else and come back to the document, macros work fine.

Any idea how this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the .docm file has been edited and saved in Word for **Mac OS**, for some bizarre reason the event trigger disappeared, but when you open VBE (Alt+F11), it comes back, hope this helps with someone with same problem.